# Principle of Relativity and the invariance of Newton's law in IRFs

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, differential-geometry, reference-frames, relative-motion, galilean-relativity

Newton's law are form invariant under the coordinate substitutions:

$$
\tilde{x^{i}}=x^{i}+a^{i}
$$

This means that Newtons' equation of motion,

$$
F^{i}=m \frac{d^{2} x^{i}}{d t^{2}}
$$

(where $i=1,2,3)$ is the same in terms of the $\tilde{x}^{i}$
Is this the Gallielian Invariance ?
How would I prove this ?

2. If we define new set of coordinates as

$$
y^{i}=y^{i}\left(x^{k}\right) .
$$

How would I find the equations of motion in these new cordinates assuming that $x^{k}$ are coordinates in an inertial frame? Which textbook should I be looking at ?

Comment: Is i  equal  k ?  In your question

Comment: No it doesn’t seem. There are two parts to the question.

Answer (score 0):

$\def \b {\mathbf}$

Newton's  equation
\begin{align*}
 &m\,\ddot{\mathbf{x}}=\b F(\b x~,\dot{\mathbf{x}})\tag 1
\end{align*}
with the new set of coordinates (where $~i=k~$)
\begin{align*}
  &\b y=\b y(\b x)\quad \Rightarrow
  \dot{\b{y}}=\underbrace{\frac{\partial \b y}{\partial \b x}}_{\b A(\b x)}\dot{\b x}\quad\Rightarrow\\
\end{align*}
assume that $~\det(A)\ne 0~$
\begin{align*}
  &\dot{\b x}=\b{A}^{-1}\ \dot{\b{y}}=\b J(\b x)\,\dot{\b{y}}\tag 2
\end{align*}
with
\begin{align*}
 \ddot{\b{x}}=\b J\,\ddot{\b{y}}+\frac{\partial \dot{\b{x}}}{\partial\b y}\,\dot{\b{y}}
\end{align*}
and  equation (1)

\begin{align*}
 &m\,\left(\b J\,\ddot{\b{y}}+\frac{\partial \dot{\b{x}}}{\partial\b y}\,\dot{\b{y}}\right)=\b F(\b x~,\dot{\mathbf{x}})\quad,\text{or}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
 &m\,\b J^T\,\b J\ddot{\b{y}}=\b J^T\,\b F(\b x~,\dot{\b{x})}-m\,\b J^T\,\frac{\partial \dot{\b{x}}}{\partial\b y}\,\dot{\b{y}}\tag 3
\end{align*}

thus the Newton's equation (1) transfered to equation (2) and (3)